# Magento 2 : How to correctly return 401 unauthroized in graphql request

Tags: magento2, exception, graphql, authentication

Existing Magento GraphQLExceptions return 200-th http code.

What would be a correct way to throw 401 for example? Or at least show custom status code in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do so without modifying (create a plugin, observer or overwrite) the basic Magento controller responsible for GraphQL.

You can check how it is realised in Magnento in the `vendor/magento/module-graph-ql/Controller/GraphQl.php` in method `dispatch`:

```
/**
 * Handle GraphQL request
 *
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 * @return ResponseInterface
 * @since 100.3.0
 */
public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
{
    $this->areaList->getArea(Area::AREA_GRAPHQL)->load(Area::PART_TRANSLATE);

    $statusCode = 200;
    $jsonResult = $this->jsonFactory->create();
    $data = $this->getDataFromRequest($request);
    $result = [];

    $schema = null;
    try {
        /** @var Http $request */
        $this->requestProcessor->validateRequest($request);

        $query = $data['query'] ?? '';
        $variables = $data['variables'] ?? null;

        // We must extract queried field names to avoid instantiation of unnecessary fields in webonyx schema
        // Temporal coupling is required for performance optimization
        $this->queryFields->setQuery($query, $variables);
        $schema = $this->schemaGenerator->generate();

        $result = $this->queryProcessor->process(
            $schema,
            $query,
            $this->contextFactory->create(),
            $data['variables'] ?? []
        );
    } catch (\Exception $error) {
        $result['errors'] = isset($result['errors']) ? $result['errors'] : [];
        $result['errors'][] = $this->graphQlError->create($error);
        $statusCode = ExceptionFormatter::HTTP_GRAPH_QL_SCHEMA_ERROR_STATUS;
    }

    $jsonResult->setHttpResponseCode($statusCode);
    $jsonResult->setData($result);
    $jsonResult->renderResult($this->httpResponse);

    // log information about the query, unless it is an introspection query
    if (strpos($data['query'], 'IntrospectionQuery') === false) {
        $queryInformation = $this->logDataHelper->getLogData($request, $data, $schema, $this->httpResponse);
        $this->loggerPool->execute($queryInformation);
    }

    return $this->httpResponse;
}
```

For your purpose you can create a plugin for this method and correct a status code in response. Also you can update the body in the response object in such a plugin.

By default there is two status codes available: **200 (regular)** and **500 (any uncaught exception)**.